# Microsoft Flow executes an SQL action twice instead of once

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates, power-automate

We are using Flow now for a while to automate certain processes. So far we are pretty pleased. However, we have noticed that something has happened that we can't seem to find on the internet or in other Flows we already have.

In short, our flow handles a mailbox (when a new email arrives) and does all kind of actions depending on the email. We have noticed that in 1 Flow instance, where a SQL insert action is done, it has been executed 2 times within the same flow.

So the Flow runs one time, the SQL action is also only declared once within this flow but for some reason, it seems to be executed twice (the SQL action that is).

Does anyone have an idea on what the cause might be?

Thank you all in advance for any help!
Have a good day
Kind regards.

Comment: This is broad question, please add where SQL action is executed twice. In ssis or agent job or any automatic process ?

Comment: @Ven This is done in a Microsoft Flow (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/), we have no power over the SQL action except setting the connectionstring and selecting available tables and fill in properties. It is happening on a Insert action. This is an image of it: https://imgur.com/a/IyCBZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that whenever a Flow was failed, i modified the Flow and solved the reason why it failed, but when resubmitting it, this was causing the double record into the SQL database so it was actually my own fault.

Glad its found :) Not flow its fault.
Have a good one !
Kind regards